# SuiteCRM/Sugar CRM 6.5: Never Redeploy a Package in a Production Environment?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm reading documentation at it says that you should never redeploy a package, but what if we modify/add additional Logic Hooks as time goes by?

We need to click "deploy" after these modifications, but it says we shouldn't..

Does it mean we need to publish the package, perform changes in the zip then re-install the zip?

Just trying to get a sense of the work flow.

Comment: My guess is that the main concern is about possible Studio changes getting partially overridden by reinstalled Module Builder packages. That is because the reinstall may cause the main module files to get a more recent modification date than the customizations, effectively overruling them. If your package only contains Logic Hooks (in custom/Extensions) and **not** base Module files (in modules/), then that particular issue shouldn't be a problem though.

Comment: @Jay thank you Jay! Do you know if publishing the .zip of the package will also save the studio changes?

Comment: I'm only familiar with SugarCRM, not SuiteCRM. In Sugar Studio Changes can only be exported separately in Studio somewhere. They are *not* saved in .zip files of the Module Builder.
So it's possible to export the Studio-Changes from Studio seperately and import them after importing the Module Builder package.